# Triggers not working

Tags: trigger

My previous problem is not resolved I have a Custom filed in accounts which is name as No of contacts now I have to write trigger after update which follows the logic of if I put no of contacts more than the present value then the difference should create a contact( for ex Old value of contact = 8 new value 10 then 2 new contacts should be created ) if ( Old valve of contact = 10 and new value = 8 then 2 contacts should be deleted ) how can I achieve this. I wrote the below trigger but it is not working correctly ( if old was 12 and new value 10 it is giving me an exception error ) ( if old value 12 and the new value is 13 it creates 1 extra contact but if I update again the new value to 12 all contact gets deleted)

Ideal I want the same no of contacts should be there in the contact related list as per the No.of contacts mentioned in the account custom field value

```
trigger trigger17 on Account (after update) {
    for(Account a:trigger.new){
        if(trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c <a.Number_of_contacts__c){
            System.debug(a.Number_of_contacts__c- trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c);
            for(Decimal i=1;i<=(a.Number_of_contacts__c- trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c);i++){
                contact c = new contact();
                c.AccountId =a.Id;
                c.LastName = a.Name;
                Insert c;
            }
        }
        if(trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c >a.Number_of_contacts__c){
            List<Contact> con = [Select id,name,accountid from contact where accountid =: a.id];
            System.debug(con);
            Decimal Diff = trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c - a.Number_of_contacts__c;
            System.debug(Diff);
            For(Contact c : Con){
                for(Integer i = 1 ; i<= Diff; i++){
                    Delete c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
     }
```

Comment: Curious to know the purpose of this as it seems the contacts would have no purpose other than to exist. They are being randomly deleted so the info in them is unimportant.  Genuinely curious

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't make DML's inside `for` loop, or any other loop. There are number of articles on the best practices that I would recommend you to read.

- [Apex best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)
- [Apex's 15 commandments](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/apex-best-practices-15-apex-commandments.html)

As for your trigger now, try the below pseudo code, and build on it. I am not developing the entire thing, so you would learn more and understand things by do-it-yourself. :-)

```
trigger trigger17 on Account (after update) {
    Map<Id,integer> contactsToAdd = new Map<Id, integer>(); // map key is AccoundId
    Map<Id,integer> contactsToDel = new Map<Id, integer>(); // map key is AccoundId

    for(Account a:trigger.new){
    if(trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c <a.Number_of_contacts__c){
        contactsToAdd.add(a.Id, a.Number_of_contacts__c - trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c);
        }
        if(trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c >a.Number_of_contacts__c){
        contactsToDel.add(a.Id, trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c - a.Number_of_contacts__c);
        }
    }

    // loop through contactsToAdd map to insert contacts against each AccountId
   // remember to not insert inside loop, but make a list and build it in the loop then make dml outside the loop.

    // loop through contactsToDel map to delete contacts against each AccountId
}
```